# Remove the decimal in the value inside mustache

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I'm trying to create a template where one of a text box's value is:

```
value="{{selection_qty}}";
```

the value of `{{selection_qty}}` is decimal

I want to remove the decimal.How could I do it using php?

I tried to put it inside php code but it didn't work.

```
value="<?php echo number_format({{selection_qty}}); ?>"
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve the decimal place value? If not then it is easy to do with pure javascript.

Comment: @DanielShillcock  {{selection_qty}} is Magento's template directive and I am not sure how will I store it in a variable.